# SQL select and join 4 tables

Tags: mysql

I'm new to SQL, trying to join 4 tables pictured below:

Here's what I have, but I don't currently have access to the SQL server (its down, and I don't own it so I just have to wait).

```
SELECT customerName, address, address2, postalCode, phone, country, city 
FROM [CUSTOMER] C JOIN ADDRESS A ON C.addressId = A.addressId 
JOIN CITY I ON A.cityId = I.cityId 
JOIN COUNTRY P ON P.countryId = I.countryId");
```

Is this the proper way to join my tables?

[image: city table]

[image: country table]

[image: customer table]

[image: address table]

Comment: Yes. Why? Btw. please edit your question and provide table structures in text form. There is absolutelly no good reason to use pictures just to post text, only downsides - ie content of pictures can't be indexed by search engines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks fine. `CUSTOMER` doesn't need `[` or `]`, that's a Microsoft SQL server syntax.

Comment: Alright, I was just going off of what I read here: https://www.dofactory.com/sql/join

Comment: Probably best not to use the SO people to validate SQL, its a bit lazy. Install a MySQL locally or use https://www.db-fiddle.com / http://sqlfiddle.com/ / http://dbfiddle.uk/ to experiment with.